# serde_json: Deserialize deeply nested JSON object

Tags: json, rust, deserialization, json-deserialization, serde

### Problem

I'm parsing an JSON API response I can't control with rust and [serde_json](https://docs.rs/serde_json/).

The response looks like this (some fields truncated):

```json
{
  (... other fields)
  "contentJsons": {
    "anchors": [
      {
        (... other fields)
        "name": "This is a name",
        "json": {
          "elements": [
            (... the important objects)
          ],
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, I only want to collect `contentJsons.anchors[].name` and all the objects in `contentJsons.anchors[].json.elements`. How do I do that the easiest way?

### Solution 1 (too verbose)

I could write a struct for every nesting layer... ugh!

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct ProductListJsonResponse {
    content_jsons: ContentJsons,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct ContentJsons {
    anchors: Vec<Anchor>,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Anchor {
    name: String,
    json: Json,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Json {
    elements: Vec<Element>,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Element {
    // ... useful info
}
```

### Solution 2 (unreadable; bad type safety)

I could also parse it dynamically... which is what I wanted to avoid by using serde_json.

```rs
let elements: Vec<(&str, &Vec<serde_json::Value>)> = json
    .get("contentJsons")
    .unwrap()
    .get("anchors")
    .unwrap()
    .as_array()
    .unwrap()
    .iter()
    .map(|anchor| {
        (
            anchor.get("name").unwrap().as_str().unwrap(),
            anchor
                .get("json")
                .unwrap()
                .get("elements")
                .unwrap()
                .as_array()
                .unwrap(),
        )
    })
    .collect();
```

### What I would like

Is there any way to derive `Deserialize` while flattening nested paths?

Something like this (the `json_path` attribute is fictional) or even shorter:

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct ProductListJsonResponse {
    #[serde(json_path = "contentJsons.anchor")]
    anchors: Vec<Anchor>,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Anchor {
    name: String,
    #[serde(json_path = "json.elements")]
    elements: Json,
}
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Element {
    // ... useful info
}
```